# asp.net best practices for saving global data on server side

Tags: asp.net, server-side, httpapplication

I need to manage a dictionary that saves userID + username for every user that logs in.
When the user makes an ajax call, I want to check if the userID in the cookie exists in the dictionary.

Where is the best place to store the data?
Of course it has to be on the server and all the users should be able to access the data, so HttpApplication is the recommended object to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yip the Application object would be the right place to store it. 
But, I fail to see in what scenario you would ever want to do this?

Other options would be a DB, File (XML), etc., but the Application object would be the fastest I think.

Comment: Hi @Jacques, Thanks for your reply! I want to store for every logged in user the userID + username. I will store the UserID in the cookie, and when I will get a request I will search the UserID in the table and I will know the username. Of course, userID will be much more sophisticated than just a number, and the username will be other required data... Does it sound like the way to do it?